# C# textbox programming

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program the textboxes, so they do their instructions AFTER the textbox is left. Any ideas on how to do it? I tried smth with KeyUp, but don't really know how it works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace For_homework
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var LoopResult = new List<int>();
        var LoopParameters = new List<int>();
        LoopParameters = TakeInput();
        LoopResult = Looping(LoopParameters);
        Result(LoopResult);
        FinalResult(LoopResult);
    }
    private List<int> TakeInput()
    {
        var Loop = new List<int>();
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox3.Text));
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox5.Text));
        Loop.Add(int.Parse(textBox6.Text));
        return Loop;
    }//Take the input
    private List<int> Looping(List<int> LoopParam)
    {
        var LoopSum = new List<int>();
        LoopSum.Add(0);
        LoopSum.Add(0);
        for (int i = LoopParam[0]; i <= LoopParam[1]; i += LoopParam[2])
        {
            LoopSum[0]+=i;
        }
        for(int i = LoopParam[3]; i <= LoopParam[4]; i += LoopParam[5])
        {
            LoopSum[1]+=i;
        }
        return LoopSum;
    }//Do the loop and summarize
    void Result (List<int> LoopResult)
    {
        resultA.Text = ""+LoopResult[0];
        resultB.Text = ""+LoopResult[1];
    }//Give result
    void FinalResult(List<int> LoopResult)
    {
        if(LoopResult[0]>LoopResult[1])
        {
            WhoWins.Text = "Player A wins";
        }
        else if(LoopResult[1]>LoopResult[0])
        {
            WhoWins.Text = "Player B wins";
        }
        else
        {
            WhoWins.Text = "It's a draw";
        }
    }//Give final result
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (i < 1 || i > 6)
            label3.Text = "Wrong number";
    }//Texbox evaluation

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        if (i < 7 || i > 18)
            label4.Text = "Wrong number";
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        if (i < 1 || i > 6)
            label7.Text = "Wrong number";
    }//Textbox evaluation

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
        if (i < 7 || i > 18)
            label8.Text = "Wrong number";
    }
}
}
```

[The form itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCW4E.png)

It told me my post is mostly code so I need to add more details

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is LostFocus TextBox Event that might be useful for you in this case:

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

And don't forget to register event in your designer file as

```
textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_LostFocus);
```

Comment: Where should I register the event?

Comment: In your Form1.Designer.cs file in InitializeComponent() method under this.textBox1 declaration

Comment: So I need 4 different Initialize components? Cause I have 4 textboxes

Comment: No they all initialized in InitializeComponent(), but youll need to write textBox_LostFocus and register EventHandler for each of them.